# Predicate condition to RemoveAll items off a list based on a condition not working

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I have two List as defined below

```
IEnumerable<Type01> newItems

List<Type02> oldItems
```

I simply want to remove the items in the new list that are same as the items in the old list

Even though no exception/errors are thrown , the required objective is not fulfilled here

any idea why that might be ?

```
foreach (var item inoldItems )
{
    newItems.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Name == item.Name);
}
```

Comment: `.ToList()` creates **new** `List<T>` from which you remove the items; note, that *original* `newItems` is not changed

Comment: oh I see !
any suggestion to how I can apply the removeAll to the required list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `ToList()` creates a *new* list from which the items are removed

```
 newItems.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Name == item.Name);
```

since you don't assign this list back but throw it away, nothing happends. If you want to remove all `item`s from `newItems` if their names are in `oldItems` you can just *filter them out* with a help of `Where`:

```
 newItems = newItems
   .Where(item => !oldItems.Any(old => old.Name == item.Name))
   .ToList(); // If you want to have a list
```

Comment: I think, in your solution, it should be assignment only, not declaration.

Comment: @as.if.i.code: You are quite right, I'm sorry for the typo